# WYSIWYG editor not in a post editor?

Tags: admin, wp-admin, wysiwyg

It is possible to use the WYSIWYG editor in theme settings (not in a post editor)?

Answer (score 0):

Yep! Check out [wp_editor()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor). It was a one of the big new features in WP 3.3.